# How do detection perks work against The Dredge using their power?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

Spine Chill says: *"Whenever the Killer is looking in your direction when they are within 36 metres of you, Spine Chill activates"*

Premonition says: *"Receive an auditory warning upon looking in the Killer's direction within a 45 ° cone within 36 metres."*

How do these detection perks work against The Dredge, specifically when they are in a locker or in transition towards a locker?

Example:

- I am a Survivor with Spine Chill and want to lock a locker.
- The Dredge is using their power to teleport towards the locker that I am standing in front of.

When, if ever, does my Spine Chill activate? Does it activate while the Killer is in transition, so once they are close enough to me my Spine Chill activates and I can decide not to lock the locker, or does it activate only once they have actually arrived **inside** the locker?

Does it work the same for Premonition? I.e. will it trigger only once the Killer has arrived in the locker or can I detect the Killer while they are transitioning?

Comment: Note: I didn't specifically ask about aura reading perks because to me the answer is obvious, during transition you don't "exist" so you can't be seen and lockers block aura reading. If that is wrong then please correct me in an answer.